# How to return value from request function in NODE JS?

Tags: node.js, request, node-modules

I'm writing app in node.js and using **npm request** package.

I need to save value from function **getData()** into variable **num**.

```
const getData = () => {
    request({url: 'url.com', json: true}, (error, response) => {
        response.body.numbers;    
    });
    return // somehow to return value
}

const num = getData();
```

I cannot figure out how to return value/response from request function. Variable num **cannot** be inside any function. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest you first stop using the `request()` library because it has been deprecated and should probably not be used for new projects.  I'd suggest the `got()` library instead, but there are plenty of alternatives to look at [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).

Comment: Then, I'd suggest you use promises, not plain callbacks.

Comment: I used Promises and Callbacks, but it did not work for me because I cannot put the variable inside any functions - the code must be `const num = getData();`

Comment: Your code does not have to be `const num = getData()`.  If you really require that, then you need a different programming environment because node.js does not do that.  But, chances are 99.9999999% that something else can be rewritten to work with an asynchronous response from a promise.  You just need to learn how to do that.  For example if `getData()` returns a promise that resolves to the final value, then you can do `const num = await getData();`.  But, the code that uses `num` can also be put inside a `.then()` handler from the promise with a little code reorganization.